# How to fill in a formula into adjacent cells in org-mode spreadsheet?

Tags: org-mode, org-table, calc, spreadsheet

For example, in the following table

```
|------------+------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----|
| Pobability |        0.1 | 0.2 | 0.3 | 0.4 | 0.5 | 0.6 | 0.7 | 0.8 | 0.9 |
| Odds       | =B1/(1-B1) |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
| Logit      | =ln(B2)    |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
|------------+------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----|
```

I'd like to automatically fill

- C2 with `=C1/(1-C1)`, D2 with `=D1/(1-D1)`, etc.
- C3 with `=ln(C2)`, D3 with `=ln(D2)`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Org mode spreadsheet is not like Excel: you don't create formulas in one cell and then propagate them to other cells (well, you *can* - do `C-h i g (org)Field and range formulas`, but propagating them is basically a matter of cutting and pasting). You can instead use a `#+TBLFM` after the table to do all that:

```
|------------+------------+------------+-------------+-------------+-----+------------+------------+-----------+-----------|
| Pobability |        0.1 |        0.2 |         0.3 |         0.4 | 0.5 |        0.6 |        0.7 |       0.8 |       0.9 |
| Odds       | 0.11111111 |       0.25 |  0.42857143 |  0.66666667 |  1. |        1.5 |  2.3333333 |        4. |        9. |
| Logit      | -2.1972246 | -1.3862944 | -0.84729786 | -0.40546510 |  0. | 0.40546511 | 0.84729785 | 1.3862944 | 2.1972246 |
|------------+------------+------------+-------------+-------------+-----+------------+------------+-----------+-----------|
#+TBLFM: @2$2..@2$> = @1/(1-@1) :: @3$2..@3$> = ln(@2)
```

Do `C-h i g (org) References RET` for the details of how to refer to cells.